# Could not find driver - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have successfully uploaded my project on my cpanel. The application is running now but when i try to log in, i get an error, `could not find driver`. I have inserted the database credentials in the .env file as well but then, i still get this same error.

Is there any another thing i have to do in my env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=pass

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=


PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Comment: Please output the full error message. What kind of exception is it? Is it a `PDOException`? If so, then your server doesn't have the PDO Drivers installed for PHP. If you manage the server yourself, you can install this in a shell prompt. Otherwise, you need to consult your hosting provider.

Comment: `CACHE_DRIVER=array` change it to `CACHE_DRIVER=file`

Answer (score 0):

I think your PHP version is causing you the trouble, had u switched it already to php version 5.6 or later ?